# Multilingual headless cms with support for articles

Tags: multilingual, headless-cms

I'm looking for headless cms with good support for several languages. It is my first project with headless cms so i tried to find something on my own but i couldn't find solution which i want. I decided to use strapi but it has poor (or maybe i miss something) internalization API. As i saw i can provide multiple language but just for some word's/sentences.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/i18n.html#usage

But my question is about some solution that can distinguish content built with content builder (some articles etc), or maybe if we cannot achieve that in strapi, is there some other **free** headless cms with that feature ? I couldn't find that and i've not seen any article about achieving that behaviour.

Best regards and thank You in advance.

Comment: Directus looks like a nice candidate...
https://docs.directus.io/guides/i18n.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[contentful](http://contentful.com/) has good multi-lingual content support but it's SaaS so you can't host it yourself.

> Pricing is based on the number of spaces and users you need, plus a platform fee.

[Directus](https://directus.io/) is free (on-prem PHP) or pay (Saas) and supports content in many languages via "translation" fields which are returned as specified by the [lang parameter](https://docs.directus.io/api/reference.html#language) in the API.